# how to expose http endpoints on two ports in node-red

Tags: docker, http, node-red

I want run one node-red instance (inside docker) and expose http endpoints on two ports, for example :1880 and :1881. How to configure node-red to listen on two ports?

Why I need two ports? I want hide node-red portal, and use it only as API service. So I want expose my API for example on 1881, and 1880 permanently close with `ufw`. If I want edit node-red using portal, I can unblock 1880 with `ufw`. Of course my Node-red instance have dashboard protected with password, but moreover I want hide all associated with node-red interface.

Comment: Do you want both ports pointing to 1880 on the inside ?

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77342734/edit) to describe the actual problem you are trying to solve here, why do you think you need to expose 2 ports?

Comment: thank You @hardillb I just clarify my question

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77342734/edit) the original question, not as a comment on an answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit curious as to why you want to do this. But there are definitely ways to do it. Here's an example using docker-compose and nginx. Nginx will listen on ports 1880 and 1881 and pass any requests on to the node-red container.

Create an Nginx config file called nginx.conf with this content

```
server {
    listen 1880;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nodered:1880/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 1881;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nodered:1880/;
    }
}
```

and a docker-compose.yml file with this

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodered:
    image: nodered/node-red
  proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    ports:
      - 1880:1880
      - 1881:1881
```

Spin up the containers using `docker compose up -d` and you should be able to reach node-red on both `http://localhost:1880/` and on `http://localhost:1881/`.

Comment: Thank You for this case, it is very interesting!
How to do it similar, but everything what is send to: <IP>:1881 redirect to <IP>:1880/nameofmyendpoint
So on <IP>:1880 I still want use node-red dashboard, but if I finish configuration, I want to hide <IP>:1880 with `ufw` and use only endpoint <IP>:1881 where You cannot ask directly to node-red portal on <IP>:1880

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution here is NOT 2 http ports.

You should move the editor off the root path and move the dashboard to the root. The editor root is controlled by `httpAdminRoot` option in the `settings.js` and the dashboard root is `ui.path` option. See the docs here:
https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/configuration

You should then ensure that the `adminAuth` is enabled to ensure that only you can log into the editor.

How to secure the editor is documented here:

https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red